# Change the conflict clause

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm wanting to change the definition of an existing table to include a unique column, with an `ON CONFLICT REPLACE` statement. I do know that the way to add a unique constraint in runtime is as below, but I can't figure out how to add or change a conflict resolution clause. Any help is appreciated!

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS someIndexName ON someTable(someColumn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite, indexes do not have a conflict resolution clause.

The [ALTER TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) does not support adding constraints to existing columns.

You have to recreate the table (or database) with the constraint.

Comment: Pity, I was really hoping I wouldn't have to recreate the table. Thanks!